# Where does gcloud store its defaults?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

Following [this Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/quickstart) I set a default project like this

```
$ gcloud config set project lfs258
Updated property [core/project].
$ gcloud config get-value project
lfs258
```

The project lfs258 doesn't exist on my GCP account, though, so I'm surprised that I could set it as the default.  When I try to see where gcloud stores its defaults there is no `.gcloud/` directory.

Where does gcloud store its defaults?  `kubectl` stores them in `.kube/config` but I can't find a similar config file for gcloud.

Answer (score 34):

To be more specific `gcloud` supports multiple configurations. Run

```
gcloud config configurations list
```

to see full list.

If user did not create configuration explicitly he/she gets configuartion named `default`, and as a result properties set via

```
gcloud config set ...
```

command will get stored in

```
~/.config/gcloud/configurations/config_default
```

If you create new configuration

```
gcloud config configurations create my_settings
```

then properties will be stored in

```
~/.config/gcloud/configurations/config_my_settings
```

Note as a user you should not care where they are stored, and if you need to programatically access them a better option is to run

```
gcloud config list --format=json
```

you can even access specific configuration (not just currently selected) by doing

```
gcloud config list --format=json --configuration=my_setting
```

Answer (score 17):

To be more generic, you can always run `gcloud info` to print out a bunch of diagnostics information to display all the configuration files and locations as well as logs and much more. Below is the `gcloud info` output on my environment, as you can see the configuration files are in 
**User Config Directory:** section.

```sh
$ gcloud info                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Google Cloud SDK [239.0.0]

Platform: [Mac OS X, x86_64] ('Darwin', 'foorbar.local', '18.2.0', 'Darwin Kernel Version 18.2.0: Thu Dec 20 20:46:53 PST 2018; root:xnu-4903.241.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64', 'x86_64', 'i386')
Python Version: [2.7.15 (default, Nov 27 2018, 21:40:55)  [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)]]
Python Location: [/usr/local/opt/python@2/bin/python2.7]
Site Packages: [Enabled]

Installation Root: [/Users/devy/.google-cloud-sdk]
Installed Components:
  kubectl: [2019.03.17]
  core: [2019.03.17]
  gcloud: []
  docker-credential-gcr: []
  gsutil: [4.37]
  bq: [2.0.42]
  alpha: [2019.02.22]
System PATH: [REDACTED]
Python PATH: [REDACTED]
Cloud SDK on PATH: [True]
Kubectl on PATH: [/usr/local/bin/kubectl]

Installation Properties: [/Users/devy/.google-cloud-sdk/properties]
User Config Directory: [/Users/devy/.config/gcloud]
Active Configuration Name: [default]
Active Configuration Path: [/Users/devy/.config/gcloud/configurations/config_default]

Account: [devy@foobar.com]
Project: [foo-bar]

Current Properties:
  [core]
    project: [foo-bar]
    account: [devy@foobar.com]
    disable_usage_reporting: [True]
  [container]
    cluster: [foobar]
  [compute]
    region: [us-central1]
    zone: [us-central1-a]

Logs Directory: [/Users/devy/.config/gcloud/logs]
Last Log File: [/Users/devy/.config/gcloud/logs/2019.03.19/16.39.09.777341.log]

git: [git version 2.19.1]
ssh: [OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3]
```

In this particular case, you can run `gcloud info | grep 'User Config'` to list the location of the config files, regardless if you custom install it or not.

Answer (score 5):

It is stored in `~/.config/gcloud/configurations/config_default`

Answer (score 0):

Kind of annoying that it doesn't seem to be possible to store it as part of a project source code for example.

Our developers have to manually set both the region and project every time a project is checked out.

Answer (score 0):

To those using quicklabs the default configuration is stored at:

```
/tmp/tmp.KeT141EpoV/configurations/config_cloudshell-5880
```

In order to find the correct location, please refer to [@Devi answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55249740/2640467)